# Is there an event handler after scanning QR code on iPhone?

Tags: ios, qr-code

When a QR code is scanned off of an iPhone (like for an electronic boarding pass), is there an event handler that can capture the fact that a scan of the code has occurred?

Comment: Yes ... very much ... which qr reader are referring to ?

Comment: I was actually referring to an event in the iPhone. So if you display a QR code from an iPhone, and a reader captures it, is there an event that an iPhone app can use to understand that a scan has occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The iOS device has no idea that the current app is displaying a QR code and there is no way for the iOS device (or the current app) to know that some external device scanned whatever happens to be displayed on the screen.