# Is there an event listener that calls a Solidity function upon accessing a QR code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, qr-code

I'm currently working on a project where I want someone to be able to scan a QR code from their metamask and have that URL endpoint call a solidity smart contract function they can accept after it loads them in. I'm currently using the react package from [the NPM site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode). Is there an event listener syntax like onClick that I can do? (Something like onAccess(), which calls the Solidity function I want to be called). [Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859335/is-there-an-event-handler-after-scanning-qr-code-on-iphone) was asked in a 2013 post and the answer was no - but I'd be highly surprised if this is actually the case today. If there is another QR package that would be better for what I want to do, by all means, let me know - I just want the project to work.